# gethostbynamel() and dns_get_record() returns empty for some domains

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gethostbyname, dns-get-record

I am using a compute instance VM of Google Cloud, have installed Debian 10 and PHP 7.3.

Then tried to run this:

```
php -r "print_r(gethostbynamel('2.0.0.127.zen.spamhaus.org.'));"
```

Surprisingly it returns an empty string.

However, on any other non-Google Cloud VM it works perfectly:

```
Array ( [0] => 127.0.0.4 [1] => 127.0.0.10 [2] => 127.0.0.2 )
```

Even stranger, with gethostbyname() it works perfectly:

```
php -r "print_r(gethostbyname('2.0.0.127.zen.spamhaus.org.'));"
```

But obviously I get only one result and not all.

I tried also this command:

```
php -r "print_r(dns_get_record('2.0.0.127.zen.spamhaus.org.', DNS_A));"
```

But it returns an empty array.

So gethostbynamel() and dns_get_record() seem to show empty fields.

While gethostbyname() works perfectly.

I opened port 53 TCP for outbound traffic on Google Firewall.

Does anyone know why this behavior is happening?

If you have suggestions please share them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known and expected behaviour which has been called out in [spamhaus site](https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%2520Usage#261) as well.

It is applicable to the internal DNS resolver for your VM as well. Google DNS  will return a "not listed" (NXDOMAIN) reply from ‘Spamhaus' public DNSBL servers because there is a DNSBlock enabled for Google DNS services.

I recommend you to use  your own DNS servers when doing DNSBL queries to Spamhaus. If that is not possible,  contact [Spamhaus Technology](https://www.spamhaus.com/product/data-query-service/) for other options.

For further more information on DNSBL, refer the [link](https://www.spamhaus.com/resource-center/successfully-accessing-spamhauss-free-block-lists-using-a-public-dns/)

Comment: You are right, seems that by using a non-public DNS it works fine, using DiG with Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8) it returns empty data, while using Verizon DNS (98.113.146.9) it works fine.

Comment: To fix it system-wide, I just added "nameserver 98.113.146.9" on /etc/resolv.conf and made sure to remove the default nameserver the VM was using.